# classic report and derived columns

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a classic report 2 columns are coming from the table and the 3rd column is a derived column.

I want to compute the values of the 3rd column based on the value of the 2nd column like if the 2nd column value is 1 then I want to put '-' in the 3rd column if it is >1 then in the 3rd column I want to put 'More than one dates'

And I want to have filters in the 3rd column header with the values that I put, I this case '-' and 'More than one dates'

And when I select the filters I want the report to be filtered accordingly.

I have a put a screen shot of the report.

Please can anyone let me know how to accomplish this.

Any help will be more than welcome
Apex 5.1 and Firefox
[Snap Shot of the Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fDGe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT-Statement should look something like this:

```
select ULA_ORDER_NUMBER,
   COUNT,
   CASE WHEN COUNT = 1 THEN '-' ELSE 'More than one dates' END as FILTER
from YOUR_TABLE
```

For the filter just "double click" on the COUNT column header.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Hope this helps you.